# Facebook Graph API locale parameter broken?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, locale

This API URL gives me the front page of VitaminWater's Facebook page (http://www.facebook.com/vitaminwater):

https://graph.facebook.com/50540568485?fields=id,name,link,picture,posts.fields(message,picture,link,likes)&access_token=...

They have a good deal of content targeted at people in Germany, but no matter what I do, I can't get the API to return it - it always gives me English content. I've tried setting the parameter "locale=de_DE" per [Facebook's API reference documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/locale/), as well as passing headers such as "Accept-Language: de" and "Accept-Language: de-DE" None of this works. Is this just broken, or is there some other way to retrieve the content for a specific locale I should be using?

Answer (score 1):

I have no solution but I can confirm that something in API is broken. We are working with monitoring tools from different providers and since March 13 this problem persists and hasn't been solved. Posts from personal and fanpages appearing only randomly in German language.

From an information by one of the tool providers I have learned that they are working together with FB to identify and fix the problem. So maybee it is frustrating to wait but this might be the better approach.